# Regex that matches all characters until 2 white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using node.js to pick out field values in some converted text. It's pretty messy with random spaces. One line looks like this:

```
'ADDRESS: 2626 W MAIN ST                                       Tran Total $1.91.$3'
```

I know where fields start but I can't get it to sop after two white spaces. Here's what I'm trying but it returns everything to the right of 'ADDRESS:':

```
/ADDRESS:\s([[^\s{2,}]+)/
```

Is there a way to include spaces and stop at the first double space with a lookahead? This doesn't work:

```
/ADDRESS:\s(.*(q!\s{2,}))/
```

Comment: What if there aren't two white spaces, but instead the address ends with end of string or newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/ADDRESS:\s((?:\S|\s(?!\s))*)/
```

should do the trick. Any number of non-spaces or spaces not followed by a space.

Comment: I think it needs to be two spaces so that the spaces between words in the address don't stop it.

Comment: @Barmar: Spaces not followed by a space.

Comment: Yeah, this got me close enough. I realized I have some lines with a \n and some lines with multiple spaces because it's being converted with OCR. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Use a non-greedy wildcard:

```
/ADDRESS:\s.*?(?=\s{2})/
```

[REGEXR](http://regexr.com?35b6i)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do this?

```
out = input.split("  ")[0]; // two spaces in that string
```

That's more effective than a regex. Or try this:

```
var spaces = input.indexOf("  "); // again, two spaces
out = spaces < 0 ? input : input.substr(0,spaces);
```

Comment: Or `input.substring(input.indexOf(' ') + 1, input.indexOf('  '))` for the group. (Second one is two spaces. Silly comments.)

Comment: It is good option but some times we don't have a choice. For example in my case I am working on existing project where we have method to read values from pdf based on regex. I cannot change existing logic just for one value.